# iOS Deeplink to a specific ViewController retaining view controller stack

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, deep-linking

I'm developing an app for a client of mine and they want to be able to deeplink to a specific view controller from the app being terminated. Here is the current stack:

- Launch Screen
- Splash Screen (Here is where we download our config file)
- VC1
- VC2
- VC3
- VC4
- VC5

The client wants the ability, via a deeplink, to launch the app, and after the Splash Screen completes the config file download, to navigate to a specific view controller (VC1-VC5). The issue is that they want to retain the stack. So i cannot simply push VC5 from the Splash Screen because VC5 needs the ability to go back to VC4 than VC3 than VC2, etc.

What is the best way to handle this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a storyboard then you could have different seques to go to different VC's,

Comment: you could add a flag in the appDelegate. If App launched via url-scheme then set this flag. And in each VC viewDidLoad check on this flag, and just push the lower-level VC

Answer (score 4):

You can set a navigation stack all at once by using the UINavigationController setViewControllers method. Just create an instance of each view controller and pass them to your nav controller like this:

```
navController.setViewControllers([vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, vc5], animated: true)
```

Just be aware that this will overwrite all view controllers currently in the navigation stack. vc1 would become your navigation controller's root vc.

Comment: Could you have the app launch, open VC1, wait for some method to finish - like downloading the config file OP mentioned - and then transition to the traget vc - VC5 in this case?

Comment: yes, you can set the view controller stack to whatever you want. After the config file is downloaded, call the method above when you are ready to transition. Whatever is the last vc in the array will be the one shown.