# How to modify Back Stack - NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I need to modify back stack in order to provide upward navigation after receiving a Deeplink to a specific content.

Looking for something really similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789439/ios-deeplink-to-a-specific-viewcontroller-retaining-view-controller-stack) but even if I have access to the backstack and its entries I am not able to change it. Simply poping and pushing to the stack would be awesome but is it really possible ?
Currently I am just navigating to the parent by using up button but It is not what I really want.

Comment: Instead of modifying back stack, you could navigate to the page upon pressing back button, conditionally when it's opened via deep link?

Comment: it is what I am doing at the moment. But, it works with Android only. is it possible to override iOS back button? Cant get the tap event of the navigation button on iOS. Thats why I was thinking modifying the back stack is the right thing for both.

Comment: Yes, you can add tap event to the navigation button.

Comment: thank you for your interest. I will try to do the same way on iOS then. But, just want to know why I can't access the functions like setViewController, push/popViewController.

Comment: In my opinion it is not a good idea either, you are going to load multiple pages those user may or not visit by navigating back. If you handle them on back navigation, you are just creating them only when user need them. Between, it's absolutely possible to access  `push/popViewController` but you have to understand the whole logic behind frame navigation before you could customise it for yourself.